# Getting ValueError while validating the form fields using Django and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am getting the below error while validating the field using Javascript and Django.

> Error:

```
ValueError at /insert/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 1853
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

I am explaining my code below.

> insert.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm(){
        var s=document.frmfeed;
        if(s.name==''){
            alert('Please enter the name');
            return;
        }else if(s.phone==''){
            alert('Please enter the phone no');
            return;
        }else if(s.age==''){
            alert('Please enter the age');
            return;
        }else{

        }
    }
</script>

<form method="post" action=" " onSubmit="return validateForm();" name="frmfeed">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input name="name" value="{{person.name}}">
    <br>
    <label>Phone: </label>
    <input name="phone" value="{{person.phone}}">
    <br>
    <label>Age: </label>
    <input name="age" value="{{person.age}}">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{person.id}}">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

> view.py:

```
def insert(request): 
    # If this is a post request we insert the person 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        p = Person( 
        name=request.POST['name'], 
        phone=request.POST['phone'], 
        age=request.POST['age'] 
        ) 
        p.save() 
        return redirect('/') 
    else: 
        return render(request, 'insert.html', {})
```

> model.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

Here I need to check all input fields those should not be blank before submit but when I am clicking on `submit button` those error are coming. Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: can you add your insert view ?

Comment: I added the insert view.

Comment: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` means that your code is trying to convert a string into an integer but you got an empty string that'll not be converted into an int and will throw this exception. i bet the problem is in your `Person` class.

Comment: age=int(request.POST['age']) if it's an InterfField

Comment: @subhra please add your `Person` class model

Comment: I added also Person class in my post.

Comment: @subhra take a look at this [tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/).

Answer (score 1):

Your JS is not actually doing any validation, in that it is not preventing submission if the values are blank. You need to `return false` in those cases.

However, you should not do any of this. Modern browsers include form validation already, which will kick in if you add a `required` attribute on the fields.

Django itself will output that attribute - and, just as important, also validate on the server side - if you use a form class. You should definitely be doing this.

Comment: Right now I am doing blank field check but later I might go for different type validation so in that case how can i handle it.

Comment: Again, HTML5 field validation will handle that, and Django will output the correct attributes if you use a ModelForm class.

Comment: Can you share your idea for my form. any one example is enough to get basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your model contains an Integer field for age, you are passing a string to the field. `request.POST['age']` always returns a string.

Try your view edited like this,

```
def insert(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        p = Person( name=request.POST['name'], phone=int(request.POST['phone']), age=int(request.POST['age']) )
        p.save() 
        return redirect('/') 
    else: 
        return render(request, 'insert.html', {})
```

Here I need to check all input fields those should

NOTE: Assuming your`phone` field is also an Integer field. If not ignore the changes in the `phone=` field.

**EDIT**

You could specify `type= "number"` , in `input` tag of age in the form.

```
<form method="post" action=" " onSubmit="return validateForm();" name="frmfeed"> 
{% csrf_token %} 
<label>Name: </label> 
<input name="name" value="{{person.name}}" required> <br> 
<label>Phone: </label>
<input name="phone" value="{{person.phone}}" required> <br> 
<label>Age: </label> 
<input type="number" name="age" value="{{person.age}}" required> <br> 
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{person.id}}"> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: How do you know that `phone` and `age` are integers in his model ?

Comment: Inspect the error, it's clear.. and who would define a charfield for age??

Comment: Well it's true that the error is due to a bad convertion of string to an int. But personnaly i cannot answer untill i see his Person class model.

Comment: I did like `age=int(request.POST['age'])` this but still same error.

Comment: No, this is not the problem. Django will convert this as necessary - in fact the error itself shows that it is calling `int` internally. The problem, as also shown in that error, is that the value being sent is the empty string.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : Actually when user will click on button without entering anything it should show the alert prompt.

Comment: Add a `required` tag in each input tag.